# Fix Apache Virtualhost with Proxy Location

Tags: virtualhost, reverse-proxy, apache-2.4, node.js

Given the following virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/dashboards/public/dist"
    Servername local.dashboards
    ServerAlias local.dashboards

    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, HEAD"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"

    Alias /api /var/www/dashboards/laravel/public

    <Directory "/var/www/dashboards/public/dist">
        Options MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/var/www/dashboards/laravel/public">
        Options MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Location />
        ProxyPass http://localhost:3030/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3030/
    </Location>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dashboards.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dashboards.access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Can ahyone suggest why requests to local.dashboards/api are still being caught by the Location directive? I can confirm that the node server is catching the request to /api and returning a 404 page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias):

> Aliasing occurs before `<Directory>` sections are checked, so only the destination of aliases are affected. (Note however `<Location>` sections are run through once before aliases are performed, so they will apply.)

A `<Location />` will pretty much apply to everything.

How about something like `<LocationMatch !^/api>` instead?

Comment: It sounds like almost exactly what I need to do. Is there a way to specify multiple patterns to not match? I will have to add another Alias in order to make this all functional.

Comment: @NoahGoodrich You can account for multiple paths in the same regex, `<Location !^/(api|otherpath)>`